# Count number of times a character appears in a url using PHP

Tags: php

I want to count the number of times "/" appears in this url

Here is my code

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo14.png";
$url_arr = eregi(".",$url);
echo count($url_arr);
```

It displays on "1"

Comment: well, there is only one '.' ...

Comment: @Daniel: a brainfart, stress, I'll leave Stackoverflow to itself. Clearly I am in no position to think (or say) anything today :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
echo substr_count($url, '/');
```

See [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) for more information.

Comment: Great it worked.....thanks... pls wait 5 mins for me to accept the answer...stackoverflow I got to wait 5 mins......

Comment: @Jean: are you sure you didn't do something like `$url_arr = substr_count($url, '/'); echo count($url_arr);`? There is no `count()` with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo strlen($url) - strlen(str_replace("/", "", $url));
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Answer (score -1):

You could use `explode()` and `count()`:

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo14.png";
$url_arr = explode(".", $url);
echo count($url_arr);
```

The reason `eregi()` returns 1 is that `eregi()` returns the length of the matched string.

Comment: If you check my question, this is what I have used, it gives me "1"

Comment: You did not use explode(), you used eregi()